# How do I answer a question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, answers

I don't see any button that says answer this question. How do I do it?

Comment: I am sorry . I am a new user :(

Comment: Just for what little it worths, you might consider taking a look at the [tour] and [help] for this forum before asking a question. Get to know a community before participating?

Comment: Which question are you trying to answer?

Comment: Upvoting since this is perfectly fine in Meta, if a bit basic.

Comment: There is a new user who asks how to answer a question and it has 7 downvotes????! Shame on this website!

Comment: Lol - I wonder why down votes  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By typing into this box and clicking this button

vvvvvv
[image: a screenshot of me editing an answer]

Comment: This wouldn't work for a new user trying to answer a protected question. I'm guessing that may be the OP's problem.

Comment: Rand al' Thor  I believe it might have been  ; what is a protected question  ?

Comment: @FlyingSaucer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions Basically, they require at least 10 reputation to answer. It often gets applied to questions that are attracting poor answers from people who've just encountered the site. For example, a question about homosexual behavior for a given character might attract detractors, or people trying to plug their favorite slashfic.